# React useContext() not reading context values in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

This is what my code looks like:

Context.js:

```
const Context = createContext();
export default Context;
```

ContextProvider.js:

```
import Context from './Context';
const ContextProvider = () =>
{
   ....
   return(<Context.Provider value={data: 1}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
}
```

ParentClass.js:

```
const ParentClass = () => 
{
   ...
   return(
      <div>
       ...
      {boolValue ? (
      <ContextProvider>
         <ConsumerComponent/>
      </ContextProvider>) 
      </div>)
}
```

ConsumerComponent.js:

```
import Context from './Context.js';
const ConsumerComponent = () => {
   const contextData = useContext(Context);
   ...
}
```

My issue is that ConsumerComponent doesn't seem to be able to access context data; it doesn't render at all when I add the `const contextData = useContext(Context);` line, and nothing gets logged when I try to print `contextData`. Where exactly did I go wrong? From my understanding, I followed the necessary steps of creating context + a provider, making sure that the consuming component has a provider as one of its ancestor components, and then accessing the context with useContext().

Comment: `boolValue ?` won't really do much. [That's one half of a ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). What's meant to happen if `boolValue` is `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want the value prop of the Context Provider to be an object like

```
{ data : 1 }
```

you probably forgot the extra curly braces, because the first pair is the JSX syntax to interpret the content as JavaScript instead of a string.

So your value prop on ContextProvider.js file probably should look like this:

```
<Context.Provider value={{data: 1}}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
```